# Translate pre chat label

Tags: community, chat, einstein-chatbot

it's possible to translate the pre chat form from Salesforce configuration?

I try but not find anything.

My problem is to translate "First Name" and "Last Name" into pre chat form.

Comment: Hi, are you using Embedded Service Chat? If yes, then did you try to change the language in embedded_svc.settings.language? For example, if embedded_svc.settings.language = 'fr'; is used, then it will display in French. Check this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=5) for all the supported languages.

Comment: embedded_svc.settings.language solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hello, where do you find the option to change embedded_svc.settings.language?

Answer (score 0):

We have an option to translate under embedded service deployment settings.